# How to prevent Outlook from attaching images to HTML emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, html

When I send an HTML email (by just copying and pasting my website) with Outlook 2007, my clients receive the correct HTML email, but with all images attached to the email. Why does that happen, and how do I send HTML emails without those attachments?

If I send the same HTML email with Gmail, my clients receive it without the attached images.